# Purchase simulation dialog does not show up (CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync)

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, windows-8.1, simulation

I was developing an app for Windows 8. After a while I updated the project to Windows 8.1 and I got a warning, that the method *CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(String, Boolean)* from the [CurrentAppSimulator class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx) is deprecated. So I started using *CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(String)* version of it, and for some reason the purchase simulation dialog does not show up at all. [Here is a dialog I was getting using deprecated version of the method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY4h9.png)

I never needed the *WindowsStoreProxy.xml* before, but just in case I checked it and set the *IsTrial* property to false - however, the dialog does not show up, **and** the answer of the new method *CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(String)* always returns *ProductPurchaseStatus::NotPurchased*.

Maybe someone knows where is the problem?

Comment: I'll be darned if I can see why this is tagged `simulation`.  What aspect of this is related to or specific to simulation?

Comment: It is a class that Microsoft provides to simulate in-app product purchases ([CurrentAppSimulator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx)).
And yes, maybe the tag is not so related to what I am asking, I will change it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *NotPurchased* is returned, because the file *WindowsStoreProxy.xml* that is used by *CurrentAppSimulator* does not contain the requested product. You need to fill *WindowsStoreProxy.xml* with all the products you are providing to the app user. [Here are some examples, written by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator.aspx).

WindowsStoreProxy.xml is created on the first launch of the app in this location:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<app package folder>\LocalState\Microsoft\Windows Store\ApiData\WindowsStoreProxy.xml
```

Also, after every *CurrentAppSimulator.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(String)* call, when result is *ProductPurchaseStatus.Succeeded* you need to do two things:

1. Grant user the product (e.g. purchased item)
2. Inform Store, that the product fulfillment is completed successfuly - using method *CurrentApp.ReportConsumableFulfillmentAsync(String, Guid)*. Make sure, that the *FulfillmentResult* that is returned afterwards is *FulfillmentResult::Succeeded*

After these steps your item should be successfully purchased and fulfilled.

**Check out detailed explanation: [Enable consumable in-app product purchases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt219683.aspx).**

And if you need more clarification of what each *FulfillmentResult* means for the purchase, you can look up a really good explanation in the book "Universal Windows Apps with XAML and C# Unleashed" by Adam Nathan, that I found while googling these things.